# Perform JQuery actions on ajax loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to access content inside a html file that I loaded into a div using jquery.load.

My index page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
       <title>
       </title>
       <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

My script so far looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("content.html");
    $("#content").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

The content.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html >  
    <head>
        <title></title>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <h1 id="header1">
        Content
        </h1>
        <p>
            This is a paragraph
        </p>
        <p>
            This is another paragraph
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what I want to happen is:
When I click on the  tag in the content div it should display that tag's id - namely "header1", but currently its just displaying "content". How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the event handler to every element in content.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("content.html");
    $("#content, #content *").click(function(e){
         alert(this.id);
         e.stopPropagation();
     });
});
```

Or let the events propogate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content").load("content.html");
    $("#content").click(function(e){
        alert(e.target.id); //may return undefined if no id is assigned.
    });
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5JmsP/